# Microsoft Bot working in emulator but not in azure web chat

Tags: azure, testing, botframework, emulation, web-chat

I have a bot developed in Bot Framework SDK 4.0, .Net Core 2.1 . I have deployed this in local IIS and when tested with emulator locally it works well.  I have configured it in Azure, set message end point as below:
[image: Message end point at Axure]

when I tried to test with Test "Test in Web chat"  in Azure I can see 
[image]

and 404 not found in ngrok in IIS server(local). I have configured Microsoft App Id & Password in appsettings.json same as Azure. Is there any thing which I am missing here? Thanks for Help.

Comment: why is your ngrok endpoint so odd? What happens if you take the "BankingchatBot" portion out of it?

Comment: If I remove Bankingchatbot then also I am facing same issue. I added that name as 2 other bots are running on same machine. and their end point is configured as above . I think I am missing something.

Comment: It seems that deployment to inetpub folder was having issue. I publish Bot again in inetpub folder, restarted systems and it starts working.  Thanks for help.